# External PDF Viewer for TexStudio on Mac

Tags: texstudio, viewers

I have recently started using TeXstudio on Mac OS. I am more used to Windows. I have heard that there is an external PDF viewer for TeXstudio on Mac called 'Skim' but I have been unable to find a step-by-step guide on how to use the external PDF viewer with TeXstudio.

Has anyone found a good guide for this or would you recommend another PDF viewer?

Cheers,

P

Comment: The default pdf-viewer for mac called Preview is of course very user-friendly and nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Howto combine and use TeXstudio with Skim

Download Skim from here: http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/ and install the App.
(Usually unpack and drag the app to the <kbd>Application</kbd> folder.

If not already done, install latest MacTeX and TeXstudio.

In TeXstudio goto <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Configure TeXstudio</kbd> -> <kbd>Commands</kbd> -> <kbd>External PDF Viewer</kbd> and enter the path to Skim. (These steps are optional. If you have the PDF opened in Skim, any compiled changes should be seen immediately as Skim uses SyncTeX.)

If you have compiled a document, then clicking the PDF icon in the internal viewer opens Skim.

If SyncTeX is installed correctly and Skim is running, in any document that is compiled, changes should be seen instantly.

Forward/Inverse search should be done by simply <kbd>CMD</kbd>+click inside the PDF resp. the source file. If further configuration is needed see section 4.9 in the TeXstudio manual.

That's about it.

Comment: Skim does not a preset command for PDF-TeX Sync support with TeXStudio.